# How to set up hot reloading with React in a Laravel project?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, webpack-hmr

I pulled down [this starter kit](https://github.com/zaichaopan/laravel-react-spa) for Laravel/React project I'm playing about with. I'm finding that hot reloading doesn't work like it does with Vue.js. This is my script (I'm running `npm run hot`)

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'public/js/*.js'"
},
```

And this is my webpack:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-tailwind');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .purgeCss()
  .tailwind('tailwind.config.js')
  .webpackConfig({
    externals: [
      'child_process'
    ],
    node: {
      fs: 'empty'
    }
  }).sourceMaps();
```

What do I need to add to my webpack so make is so that saving my React files automatically update the page as I'm looking at it? I've tried [various](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/hot-module-replacement) different [solutions](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/937) but [nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425186/laravel-reactjs-changes-are-not-reflecting-after-change-in-my-jsreactjs-file) is working.

Surely it is possible?

Comment: "npn run watch" should check for your changes and then hot reload

Comment: Yeah that doesn't happen unfortunately. In fact, when I terminate npm run watch and refresh the content, it still shows me the React code, so it'd like Webpack is building/pointing to the wrong location?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Laravel 8.x:

```
npm run hot
```

Maybe laravel will add some packages, you'll see a weird screen error, run again and works!

If hot not exists on `package.json` just include it at scripts section:

```
"hot": "mix watch --hot"
```